# Repeat animation with new animated api

Tags: animation, react-native

React-native introduce new `Animated` API, I want to make a loop animation such as a bubble scale up then scale down and repeat that progress.

However I can not figure it out. I've tried write some code like below

```
class TestProject extends React.Component {

  constructor(): void {
    super();
    this.state = {
      bounceValue: new Animated.Value(0),
      v: 1,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.bounceValue.setValue(1.5);

    let animation = Animated.timing(this.state.bounceValue, {
      toValue: this.state.v,
    });

    setInterval(() => {
      animation.stop();

      if (this.state.flag) {
        this.state.v = 0.5;
        this.state.bounceValue.setValue(0.5);
      }
      else {
        this.state.v = 1.5;
        this.state.bounceValue.setValue(1.5);
      }

      animation.start();
    }, 5000);

  }

  render(): ReactElement {
    return (
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={{uri: 'http://image142-c.poco.cn/best_pocoers/20130517/91062013051716553599334223.jpg'}}
        />
        <Animated.Text
          style={[
            styles.test,
            {transform: [
              {scale: this.state.bounceValue},
            ],}
          ]
          }>
          haha
        </Animated.Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

but not works very well.

Any suggestion will be appreciate.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

There's now [loop animation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#loop) available:

```js
Animated.loop(
  Animated.sequence([
    Animated.timing(this.state.animatedStartValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      delay: 1000
    }),
    Animated.timing(this.state.animatedStartValue, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500
    })
  ]),
  {
    iterations: 4
  }
).start()
```

Comment: you can't set a callback at the end of the loop though

Comment: @Herno - I think you can set a callback. If you specify `iterations` the callback will be called after. Or you can call `stop` on the returned object and the callback will be called with `finished`=false. However, I'm not aware of any way to dynamically check if the loop should stop.

Comment: How do we stop this infinitely looping animation? `this.state.animatedStartValue.stop()`? This would stop only child animation though right? Not the loop?

Answer (score 40):

I use the sequence method to pass an array of animations to cycle and then repeat the function.

```
//this.state.animatedStartValue = 0;

function cycleAnimation() {
  Animated.sequence([
    Animated.timing(this.state.animatedStartValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      delay: 1000
    }),
    Animated.timing(this.state.animatedStartValue, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500
    })
  ]).start(() => {
    cycleAnimation();
  });
}
```

If I'm toggling that animation on it's own it will fade in/out, however I layer it on top of a base to mimic an active state or hotspot-style button

```
  <TouchableOpacity>
    <Animated.Image
      source={activeImageSource}
      style={this.state.animatedStartValue}}
    />
    <Image source={nonActiveImageSource}
    />
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

[React Native Sequence Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html#composing-animations)

Comment: before looping you should check if the animation finished or was canceled, otherwise you'll never be able to stop it. See my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578069/repeat-animation-with-new-animated-api/38393479#38393479

Comment: Find silyevsk's answer. This is outdated.

Comment: you can also use this.state.yourAnimation.stopAnimation()   when you componentWillUnmount

Answer (score 19):

improved version of @bcomerford answer

```
//this.state.animatedStartValue = 0;

function cycleAnimation() {
  Animated.sequence([
    Animated.timing(this.state.animatedStartValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      delay: 1000
    }),
    Animated.timing(this.state.animatedStartValue, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500
   })
  ]).start(event => {
    if (event.finished) {
      cycleAnimation();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.bootAnimation();
  }

  bootAnimation() {
    this.animation = Animated.loop(
      Animated.timing(this.state.progress, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 5000
      })
    ).start();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that 'looping' is not supported by the `Animated` api for now.

I managed to do that by start the animation again when it finished.

```
startAnimation() {
  Animated.timing(this._animatedValue, {
    toValue: 100,
    duration: 1000,
  }).start(() => {
    this.startAnimation();
  });
}
```

[image]

Looking forward to a better solution...

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example for an infinite animation using hooks and `iterations` set to "infinity". Avoids the use of the recursion in previous answers which sometimes led to funky behaviour during e2e testing for us.

```js
  const rotation = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  function runAnimation() {
    return Animated.loop(
      Animated.timing(rotation, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 1200,
        easing: Easing.linear,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
      {resetBeforeIteration: true, iterations: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER},
    );
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const animation = runAnimation();
    return () => animation.stop();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set another animation then call the animation again:

An example I did to fade text in and out:

```
  textAnimate: function() {
    Animated.timing(
      this.state.textOpacity,
      {
        toValue: 0.3,                         
        duration: 500, 
      }
    ).start(() => {
      Animated.timing(  
        this.state.textOpacity,            
        {
          toValue: 1,                    
          duration: 500,          
        }
      ).start(() => {
          this.textAnimate();
        });
    });    
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.state.textOpacity.setValue(1)
    this.textAnimate();
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's hacky, but I use this:

```
Animated.spring(this.state.rotation, {
  toValue: 5,
  stiffness: 220, // the higher value, the faster the animation
  damping: 0.000001, // never stop wiggle wiggle wiggle
}).start();
```

It's creating spring animation that will never (technically, for a very very very long time) stop waving.

For most of my cases it was enough. Also it has great performance as it does not require any JS tread action ever during animation.

If eventually you'd like to stop it gracefully:

```
Animated.spring(this.state.rotation, {
  toValue: 0,
  stiffness: 220, // the higher value, the faster the animation
  damping: 10, // never stop wiggle wiggle wiggle
}).start();
```

And it'll nicely 'slow down' until it stops.