# repeat animation conflict with InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions

Tags: animation, react-native

[react-native repeat animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578069/repeat-animation-with-new-animated-api/42640972?noredirect=1#comment72409138_42640972)

I searched how to implement a repeated animation ,and I found this.

```js
//this.state.animatedStartValue = 0;

function cycleAnimation() {
  Animated.sequence([
    Animated.timing(this.state.animatedStartValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      delay: 1000
    }),
    Animated.timing(this.state.animatedStartValue, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500
   })
  ]).start(event => {
    if (event.finished) {
      cycleAnimation();
    }
  });
}
```

It do works ,but when I use it in my project, I found that this solution will conflict with InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions, which is usually used to do something after animation.

I can use setTimeOut and so on to avoid this, but I want to ask ,is there any better solution to repeat animation , or to avoid this conflict?

Answer (score 3):

use param {isInteraction: false }can avoid this problem.

```js
//this.state.animatedStartValue = 0;

function cycleAnimation() {
  Animated.sequence([
    Animated.timing(this.state.animatedStartValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      delay: 1000,
      isInteraction: false,
    }),
    Animated.timing(this.state.animatedStartValue, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500
   })
  ]).start(event => {
    if (event.finished) {
      cycleAnimation();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing, super useful

here's a link to the docs where this is documented https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated#timing